# Chaining your own method in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app, I am used to using syntax like the following in a number of places, including helpers/application_helper.rb:

```
def my_method(x,y)
  return x+y
end
```

I am also used to calling the resulting method from basically anywhere in my app using syntax like this:

```
my_method(2,3)
```

However, I'd like to be able to use syntax like like this:

```
class_from_my_rails_app.my_method(3)
```

How and where do I define my_method so I can use it like this?

I'm happy to consult the documentation, but I just don't know what the latter style is called. What do you call it?

Many thanks,

Steven.

Comment: I don't understand: Why is there only one integer in the `class_from_my_rails_app.my_method` call?

Comment: You can leave out the `return` in your example. The final expression in a method is automatically the return value.

Comment: Mathepic, there's in one calls because I was imagining this would work like my_string.truncate(20), which takes "text" from my_string and other arguments from the parentheses. Sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe thing you want to create is called an instance method. Implemented as follows:

```
class YourClass

  def initalize(x)
    @x =x
  end

  def do_something(y)
    @x + y
  end

end
```

which you would use a follows:

```
my_class = YourClass.new(20)

puts my_class.do_something(10)
=> 30
```

But actually this is so fundamental to object oriented programming and ruby that i am surprised to even see this question.

I would suggest reading up on ruby as a language, a very good book t get you started is [The Well-grounded Rubyist](http://www.manning.com/black2/), that starts from all the basics and works it's way up into all the details.

I hope this helps. If i misunderstood your question, i apologise, and would be glad to elaborate on any part.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for. I'll check out the book too, and hopefully this will continue to be a place where those of us who are newish to Rails can still search for answers as we reach backwards into the underlying Ruby fundamentals.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're talking about creating a class method.

```
class MyClass
  def self.my_method(x,y)
    return x+y
  end
end
```

This allows you to call

```
MyClass.my_method(2,3)
```

This probably belongs in a model class, rather than a helper class, rails-wise.

Comment: Thanks. I was imagining more new_instance = MyClass.new then new_instance.my_method where at least one of x and Y come from new_instance rather than being fed in via parentheses. If that makes sense? Much as if I had invented "truncate" in my_string.truncate(20), which grabs "text" from my_string but other arguments from the parentheses.